# Trouble performing feature selection using boruta and support vector regression

Tags: python, feature-selection, svr, boruta

I was trying to select the most important features of a data set using [Boruta in python](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py). I have split the data into training and test set. Then I used [SVM regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) to fit the data. Then I used Boruta to measure feature importance.The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR

svclassifier = SVR(kernel='rbf',C=1e4, gamma=0.1)
svm_model= svclassifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

from boruta import BorutaPy

feat_selector = BorutaPy(svclassifier, n_estimators='auto', verbose=2, random_state=1)
feat_selector.fit(x_train, y_train)
feat_selector.support_
feat_selector.ranking_
X_filtered = feat_selector.transform(x_train)
```

But I get this error `KeyError: 'max_depth'`.

What might be causing this error?

Does Boruta work with any kind of models? i.e linear models, tree-based models, neural nets, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the full code, there are few things to check but I would try as follows:

Note that you are passing `svm_model` to `BorutaPy` and according to your code you should pass the fitted object that is `svm_model`

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR

svclassifier = SVR(kernel='rbf',C=1e4, gamma=0.1)
svm_model= svclassifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

from boruta import BorutaPy

feat_selector = BorutaPy(svm_model, n_estimators='auto', verbose=2, random_state=1)
feat_selector.fit(x_train, y_train)
feat_selector.support_
feat_selector.ranking_
X_filtered = feat_selector.transform(x_train)
```

**EDIT:**

After reading the implementation of Boruta and since this is based on tree models.

```
 Parameters
    ----------
    estimator : object
        A supervised learning estimator, with a 'fit' method that returns the
        feature_importances_ attribute. Important features must correspond to
        high absolute values in the feature_importances_.
```

`SVM` does not have the attribute `feature_importances_`, so `Boruta` can only receive tree models like DecisionTrees, RandomForest, XGB, etc.

If you want to use `SVM` anyway I would recommend to change the feature selection algorithm to [PermutationImportance](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/feature-importance.html), which is quite similar way of computing importance base on random repeated permutation, but in this case you will have to provide a metric to measure the decrease on performance when a feature is shuffled.